# Immersion duals spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is correct say that $(\ell_\infty)'\subset (c_0)'$?

My idea is the following:

I know that $c_0\subset\ell_\infty$. Then, the function
$$
\begin{split}
\Psi:(\ell_\infty)'&\to(c_0)'\\
f&\mapsto\Psi(f)=f|_{c_0}
\end{split}
$$
is injective.

Is correct the function? Does exist an injective function $\Psi$ such that $(\ell_\infty)'\subset (c_0)'$?

Comment: what is $c_0$ in your question?

Comment: $\ell_\infty^*$'s cardinality exceeds that of the continuum; the same can't be said for $c_0^*=\ell_1$'s cardinality.

Comment: The restriction map you define is NOT injective! This is not completely obvious but follows from the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: Thank you so much!